# Need to fetch data from the core/template in magento with the help of corePHP

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

This is the xml file that i retrieved while fetching the static page from the Magento Database.

> But {{block type="core/template"
>   template="DigitalHomes/DigitalHomes.phtml"}} is something i am not able to fetch.

```
<parameters>
<Simran>
<title>TITLE OF THE PAGE</title>
<content>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery( "#content" ).tabs(); }); // ]]></script> <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ jQuery("h4").click(function () { jQuery(".open").toggle("slow"); }); // ]]></script> <div id="contentwrap2" style="background: #333; padding: 5px; color: #ccc;"> <h1 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; color: #e47911; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 40px;">Digital Homes</h1> <p>{{block type="core/template" template="DigitalHomes/DigitalHomes.phtml"}}</p> </div>
</content>
</Simran>
</parameters>
```

Please suggest me what can we do to fetch the block content from core/template type. As this is a phtml file.